# Using an object class from external library in looping PHP

Tags: php

I use qr code library from this: [QR Code 2Amigos](http://qrcode-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

The problem is, from this library, I have to generate a qr code from each record until 1000 record from my database then display it into browser. How to optimize the time?

My code looked like this :

```
<?php
   use Da\QrCode\QrCode;
?>

<?php foreach ($modelCheckListDetail as $i => $modelCheckListDetail): ?>
    <?php
    $qrCode = (new QrCode($modelCheckListDetail->unique_key))
        ->setSize(100)
        ->setMargin(5)

    ?>
    <tr class="item">
        <td> <?= ($i + 1) ?> </td>
        <td> <?= $form->field($modelCheckListDetail, "[{$i}]unique_key")->label(false)->textInput([
                'readOnly' => true
            ]) ?> </td>
        <td> <?= Html::img($qrCode->writeDataUri()); ?> </td>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I think my problem is, I have to create an instance in every looping.
Is there another way?

Comment: You're generating and displaying 10.000 QR-codes in one go? That will certainly be slow no matter what you do. Why do you need to show all of them at once? I would use pagination, only showing a few at a time.

Comment: Sorrym=, just 1000

Comment: That's still quite a lot. Usually when you're dealing with a large output, the slowest part is actually outputting the data, not generating it. Pagination is probably still the best option.